# Cleaner approach to binding properties with multiple values angular 5

Tags: angular

I'm wondering what a cleaner approach to binding properties with multiple different values is. For example, `border` has width, style, and color. If I wanted to bind those, i could do this:

```
   <img [src]="product.imageUrl"
               [title]="product.productName"
               [style.width.px]="imageWidth"
               [style.margin.px]="imageMargin"
               [style.border.px]="borderWidth"
               [style.border.color]="borderColor"
               [style.border.style]="borderStyle"
                />
```

where the model defines these as:

```
  pageTitle: string = "Product List";
  imageWidth: number = 50;
  imageMargin: number = 2;
  borderWidth: number = 5;
  borderColor: string = "black";
  borderStyle: string = "solid";
```

It would seem to be cleaner to bind a `border` array to the property, something like this:

```
    <img [src]="product.imageUrl"
               [title]="product.productName"
               [style.width.px]="imageWidth"
               [style.margin.px]="imageMargin"
               [style.border]="border"/>
```

with the model being:

```
border: any[] = [2, "solid", "black"];
```

I'm not able to get the `[style.border]` to be set to the array in the model. I am not defining that the number should be px, and that the last two properties are strings so perhaps that is my problem.

What is a cleaner way to approach this?

Comment: [style.border] probably need value as string and not array. But prefer to use [ngStyle] for all your styles on a tag. https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I was not using the correct syntax for my border array. Replacing the previous border array with: `border: any[] = [2 ? 'solid' : 'black'];`, solves the issue.

I found the solution in the documentation (of course) here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngStyle

I hope this helps someone else in the future!

Comment: Are you sure? I think that you want to write [style.border]="border" border:string="2px solid black", or [ngStyle]="style", style:any={'border':'2px solid black'}

Comment: Yes, this does produce the desired result, however the approach you show would maybe be more in line with the docs, I'll have to test this out. Thank you!